# Are there physiological effects unique to the simultaneous consumption of alcohol and tobacco?

Tags: alcohol, nicotine, tobacco

I'm aware of the various effects of alcohol and tobacco, but are there any effects which are only present during the consumption of both? A hypothetical example would be: alcohol causes vasodilation, increasing absorption of nicotine from tobacco.